# intervention/image error when capture with mobile camera

Tags: laravel, intervention

When i uploaded image to my website from capture image from mobile camera no from the gallery
and it say " Image source not readable"
this is my code
$fileName    =  create_random_name() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

```
$img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());

$img->stream();

 Storage::disk('local')->put("public/images/{$directory}/".$fileName,$img,'public');

return $fileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will help you:

```
Storage::disk('local')->put($newFilename, file_get_contents($file));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it